# QGraphicsView and QMouseMove Event

Tags: c++, qt5, qgraphicsview

i have a borderless (no title bar) QWidget window with a QGraphicsView inside. I've overwritten mousePressEvent and mouseMoveEvent for move the window on the desktop, but when i press on the QGraphicsView this not works.

Below, the code of mousePressEvent and mouseMoveEvent:

```
void Widget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *evt)
{
    oldPos = evt->globalPos();
}

void Widget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *evt)
{
    const QPoint delta = evt->globalPos() - oldPos;
    move(x() + delta.x(), y() + delta.y());
    oldPos = evt->globalPos();
}
```

I also overwritten with the same code:

> void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *evt);
>   void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *evt);

i tried with:

```
setInteractive(false);
setDragMode(scrollHandDrag);
```

but nothing!

is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Can you post the handler code?

Comment: Why the override functions putting in the `Widget` rather than `GraphicsView`(inherit from QGraphicsView)?

Comment: I already tried in QGraphicsView

Comment: Do you want move view inside widget or move all widget by clicking on view?

Comment: all widget by clicking on view

Comment: Now it is clear. View eat all events, your clicking and moving does not reach to widget. I think that I can write good answer if you tell me structure of your program. For example Widget-layout-view, or widget-centralWidget-layout-view. Tell me please.

Comment: ok @Chernobyl, there is a QWidget (main window) -> QGraphicsView.
The QGraphicsView loads 1 QWidget.